# javascript currying

Tags: javascript, lexical-closures

I'm trying to create [curry function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry_%28programming_language%29) that can be applied to any function and return another, with 1 of the arguments applied.
Properties that I want to have:

1. If function has only one argument curry function should return value:
   f(a); curry(f,x) = f(x);
2. If function has many arguments currey should retrun curried function:
   g(a1,a2,..,aN); curry(g,x) = g2(a2,..,aN) : g2(a2,..aN)=g(x,a2,...,aN)
3. Length propery of curried function should work "as needed"
   g.length = N => curry(g,x).length = N-1

There is some implementations of curry in Prototype Framework and discussion in [one blog](http://www.dustindiaz.com/javascript-curry/). But this implementation is not good because it doesn't work well on functions with only one argument (1), and also returning function 'length' attribute is 0 (3).

For first property there is an easy implementation:

```
 function curry(f,x) {
    if (f.length == 1) return f(x);
    ...
 }
```

But I don't know how to work with 3rd rule, i.e. function can be constucted as inner function since there will be a nested Lexical Environment and will be able to use f:

```
function curry(f,x) {
   return function() { ... }
}
```

but in this case I'll no longer will able to explicitly set parameters. 
On the other hand function can be constructed with 'new Function' statement, smth like that:

```
 function curry(f,x) {
    var args = [];
    for (var i=1; i<f.length; i++) {
       args.push('a'+i);
    }
    var sa = args.join();
    return new Function(sa,"return f(x,"+sa+")");
 }
```

But in this situation f and x will unbound because anonymous function will be created in
Global Lexical Environment.

So the questions:

1. is there a way to explicitly set parameters count when creating function with function keyword?
2. is there a way to set Environment of function created with 'new Function' statement?
3. us there a way to solve my problem in any other way?

Comment: Just because a function is *declared* with a single argument doesn't mean that it doesn't *accept* more.

Comment: I find the first requirement asymmetrical. Currying a function of one argument should return a function with no arguments in my opinion...

Comment: I know that if function declared with some arguments it can accept more, but anyway there can be a situation when I want to check length attribute and solution will break this logic.
There was no answer for 1 and 2 question but the core problem is solved so I mark question as solved

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way that the [Functional](http://osteele.com/sources/javascript/functional/) library implements it is to take the parameters passed in to "curry()" as the *first* parameters to be passed. The function result of the "curry" operation will then take any additional parameters passed in when it is invoked and add them at the *end* of the argument list.  It doesn't worry at all about argument list length, because that's not a fixed thing in JavaScript generally so there's really no point.

Thus:

```
var curry = myFunction.curry("Tuesday", x + y);
```

So calling:

```
curry(100, true);
```

will be just like calling:

```
myFunction("Tuesday", x + y, 100, true);
```

Functional has another function called "partial()" that allows a more controlled substitution of parameters. When you call "partial()", you pass in a dummy argument ("_") to indicate where "holes" are in the argument list:

```
var partialFunc = myFunction.partial("Tuesday", _, 100, true, _, "banana");
```

Those two "_" parameters mean that the resulting "partialFunc" should drop first two arguments passed to it into those slots in the argument list:

```
partialFunc(x + y, "Texas");
```

is thus just like calling:

```
myFunction("Tuesday", x + y, 100, true, "Texas", "banana");
```

I heartily recommend getting that library and looking at the code involved. It's surprisingly succinct and clear.

One more thing: it's important to note that because JavaScript is not a lazy-evaluation language, this isn't *really* the same as the "curry" operation in a lazy functional language like Haskell. The distinction is that the arguments at "curry time" are *evaluated* and therefore sort-of "cooked" into the result. In a lazy language, things are different.

Answer (score 3):

```
function curry(fn, args) {
  // no need to var these, they are scoped via argument list - we overwrite them
  // convert the arguments to a real array:
  args = [].slice.apply(arguments);
  // first argument is a function:
  fn = args.shift();
  return function() {
    // get internal args
    var iArgs = [].slice.apply(arguments);
    // apply curried arguments, then our arguments:
    return fn.apply(this, args.concat(iArgs));
  }
}

function add(a,b) { return a+b; }
var add2 = curry(add, 2);
alert(add2(5)); //7

var hello = curry(add, "Hello ");
alert(hello("World!"));
```

Answer (score 2):

For years now I have used a function prototype for curry that looks like this:

```
Function.prototype.curry = function curry() {
    var fn = this, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return function curryed() {
        return fn.apply(this, args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
    };
};
```

Maybe it will suit your needs as well.

You simply use it like so:

```
function fn1(arg1,arg2) { /*...*/ }

var fn1Curried = fn1.curry('whatever'); //sets arg1
```

It will work with any number of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

```
function curry(func) {
    var initial_args = [].slice.apply(arguments, [1]);
    var func_args_length = func.length;

    function curried(args) {
        if (args.length >= func_args_length) {
            return func.apply(null, args);
        }

        return function () {
            return curried(args.concat([].slice.apply(arguments)));
        };
    }

    return curried(initial_args);
}
```