# How to write a function which can accept one or more arguments and send back addition

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have to call function in below way

```
sum(3)(2)
```

My function is:

```
sum(a,b) { return a + b }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript currying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273420/javascript-currying)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at Currying concept

```js
let sum = (a) => (b) => a + b

console.log(sum(1)(3)) // 4
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try out this approach

```
function sum(x, y) {
 if (y !== undefined) {
  return x + y;
 } else {
  return function(y) { return x + y; };
 }
}
```

To understand it better https://www.toptal.com/javascript/interview-questions